# android achartengine : font appearing as double when exported as bitmap from graph

Tags: android, achartengine

Am drawing a graph using AChartEngine where I'm having text (i.e. annotations, as they call in AChartEngine). They appear fine when seen on the screen, as you can see below :

[image]

but when the screen is saved as bitmap, the text appears with only the outline of each letter displayed as you can see below :

[image]

and this is how I get the bitmap from the view (ie. I am taking a screenshot of the graph)

```
    Bitmap bitmap;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;

    Bitmap dummy = null;
    try {
        dummy = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open("icon_add.png"), new Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1), options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(deviceWidth,
        deviceHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  // use ARGB_4444 if outofmemory

    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight() + 15);
    view.draw(c);
```

can someone please help?

Comment: Are you trying to get a "screenshot" of a specific view stored into bitmap?

Comment: yes, you are right @helleye

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
Bitmap cache;

view.buildDrawingCache(); 
cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());

view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Comment: let me try that & get back @helleye . Thanks!